# Null return from localhost php coding

Tags: php, sql, localhost

I set up my localhost, I have all my relevant files in place.  I run the php where I run the sql query, it returns NULL values.  But it should not.  I visit to the directory of the link via browser.

Can someone point me in the return direction, why it is returning NULL? I ran the SQL query, and works fine on my phpmyAdmin

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Ihavenopassword');
define('DB_NAME', 'mytablename');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
//$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT playerid, score FROM score ORDER BY playerid");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` is not what you expect. You need to fetch every item, with `fetch_assoc` for example:

```
//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hi u_mulder, strangely on my side of things. It still returns 0 results. Any possible reasons on this occurrence?

Comment: solved, thanks!  I had to use if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {